# TeX Live packages administration, tlmgr don't work on Open Suse

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I want to know how install and manage packages for TeX Live 2011 on Linux Open Suse; with Windows systems it is possible to manage packages for TeX Live with the Package Manager program included in the MiKTeX installation, but I don't now how to install and manage packages for TeX Live on Linux. I installed TeX Live 2011 with YaST2 Software Management but when I want execute the command `tlmgr` I get the following message:

```
    dev@dhcppc1:~> tlmgr
If 'tlmgr' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf tlmgr
```

So, how I can manage packages if `tlmgr` is not found or does not work? How I can "reinstall" `tlmgr`?

My TeX Live version is: TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
My OS:  Open Suse 12.2

Comment: You should read: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: You cannot. You choose to get latex from open suse, thus you have to wait until they include updated packages into their normal system updates. It is only when manually installing the TUG texlive that you get tlmgr. I do not know of any Linux dist that include it in their version of tl. I'd recommend dropping the suse tl and manually install Tug tl. There are guides for this elsewhere on this site.